# SQL Server - Conditional DELETE based on SUM from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to delete a specified student from the `Studies` table, for a specified term, if their score reaches a value of above x sPoints. I did attempt to do this and it works if I only specify which score they must be below.

If I start specifying student ID and term number in the query, it deletes all students from Studies where the student ID and term matches the one in the query without bothering to check the score.

My attempt: Student S2 has a total of 45 points in term 2 (5 in `HasStudied` and 40 in `Studies`) so he shouldn't be deleted with this query. Yet he still gets deleted when I run this query.

I'm on MS SQL server 2014.

```
DELETE FROM Studies
FROM Studies a1
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.stID AS ha 
            FROM Studies a 
            INNER JOIN HasStudied wq ON wq.stID = a.stID 
            WHERE a.stID = 'S2' AND a.termNbr = 2 
            GROUP BY a.stID 
            HAVING (SUM(wq.sPoints) + (SUM(a.sPoints))) > 50) a2 ON a1.stID = a2.ha
```

`Studies` table

```
CREATE TABLE Studies 
(
    cID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    stID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    sPoints int,
    termNbr int

    CONSTRAINT STUDIES_PK PRIMARY KEY (cID, stID),

    CONSTRAINT STUDIES_CID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES Course (cID),
    CONSTRAINT STUDIES_STID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (stID) REFERENCES Student (stID)
)
```

`HasStudied` table

```
CREATE TABLE HasStudied 
(
    cID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    stID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    grade VARCHAR (5),
    sPoints int,
    termNbr int

    CONSTRAINT HASSTUDIED_PK PRIMARY KEY (cID, stID)
    CONSTRAINT HASSTUDIED_CID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES Course (cID),
    CONSTRAINT HASSTUDIED_STID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (stID) REFERENCES Student (stID)
)
```

Data in HasStudies and Studies.

```
INSERT INTO HasStudied (cID, stID, grade, sPoints, termNbr) VALUES 
('K1', 'S2', 'D', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K1'), 1), 
('K2', 'S2', 'A', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K2'), 1), 
('K3', 'S2', 'C', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K3'), 1), 
('K1', 'S3', 'C', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K1'), 1), 
('K2', 'S3', 'E', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K2'), 1), 
('K3', 'S3', 'B', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K3'), 1), 
('K4', 'S3', 'E', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K4'), 2), 
('K5', 'S3', 'D', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K5'), 2)


INSERT INTO Studies (cID, stID, sPoints, termNbr) VALUES 
('K1', 'S1', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K1'), 1), 
('K2', 'S1', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K2'), 1), 
('K3', 'S1', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K3'), 1), 
('K4', 'S2', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K4'), 2), 
('K5', 'S2', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K5'), 2), 
('K6', 'S3', (SELECT cPoints FROM COURSE WHERE cID = 'K6'), 3)
```

EDIT 2

I did yet another test with the student S2 that has 45 points in total. If I do HAVING (SUM(wq.sPoints) + (SUM(a.sPoints))) > x) and set x to a number below 50, it deletes the student. If I set it to 50 and above, it doesn't delete the student. So even a number of 49 will delete the student.

Comment: `DELETE FROM Studies from Studies a1` you have 2 froms in this first bit, assume typo.

Comment: Could you provide sample data please? I just created a query with your example and a few records... and it works as requested: only the student with 50+ points is deleted...

Comment: Yes, sorry. The data has been put into the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

Using Union, you can get the combined set to then test for the total:

```
WITH a AS(
    SELECT sPoints 
    FROM Studies
    WHERE termNbr = 2 AND stID = 'S2'
    UNION
    SELECT sPoints 
    FROM HasStudied
    WHERE termNbr = 2 AND stID = 'S2'
)

DELETE FROM Studies
WHERE termNbr = 2 AND stID = 'S2' AND (SELECT SUM(sPoints) FROM a) > 59;
```

Original

You could try organizing your query more like this, which might make it easier to read and input the parameters you are looking for:

```
DELETE FROM Studies
WHERE termNbr = 2 AND stID = 'Bob' AND stID IN(
  SELECT s.stID FROM Studies s
  JOIN HasStudied hs ON s.stID = hs.stID AND s.termNbr = hs.termNbr
  WHERE s.termNbr = 2
  GROUP BY s.stID
  HAVING (SUM(s.sPoints) + SUM(hs.sPoints)) > 50
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6ffb8/18

Comment: This works but if I do HAVING (SUM(s.sPoints) + SUM(hs.sPoints)) > 49, it deletes the student S2 with 45 points. Anything above 50 doesn't delete the student S2

Comment: I wonder why it's not wanting to do it properly in MS SQL Server Management Studio if the query in the OP appears to be correct. I tried the query you posted as well with the same issue that if I enter 49 in the HAVING clause , it deletes the student from Studies that has 45 points. If I enter 50 in the HAVING clause, it does not delete the student.

Comment: Seems like something with the data... did you try to display the data?
SELECT a.stID, a.sPoints, wq.sPoints, a.termNbr FROM Studies a
JOIN HasStudied wq ON wq.stID = a.stID AND a.termNbr = 2 AND wq.termNbr = 2 ;

Comment: I ran that query and got this result https://s26.postimg.org/wjdhgqgnd/thsa34.jpg

Comment: Which is why 50 is the magic number. It is counting two records, in each table, two 20s and two 5s, with a total of 50

Comment: Can you post the contents of each table?

Comment: Oh damn. First results are from the Studies table and second result set is from the HasStudied table https://s26.postimg.org/iz5jjybbd/2w3lkjlksaej.jpg

Comment: Its because we didn't know that cID was involved as well. what does that represent and how should it be handled?

Comment: cID is course ID, referencing the cID in the Course table. It's a many-many relation between Student and Course so I need to keep track of what student studies/has studied which course

Comment: I updated my answer to include this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d2a29/11

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks OK and seems to work like a charm... maybe there is an error in your data?

```
DECLARE @Studies TABLE(
    cID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    stID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    sPoints int,
    termNbr int
)

DECLARE @HasStudied TABLE(
    cID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    stID VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    grade VARCHAR (5),
    sPoints int,
    termNbr int
)

INSERT INTO @Studies VALUES ('AAA', 'SSS1', 7, 11), ('AAA', 'SSS1', 13, 11), ('AAA', 'SSS1', 30, 11)
INSERT INTO @Studies VALUES ('BBB', 'SSS2', 7, 11), ('BBB', 'SSS2', 13, 11)

INSERT INTO @HasStudied VALUES ('AAA', 'SSS1', 'A', 20, 11), ('BBB', 'SSS2', 'F', 0, 11)

DELETE FROM @Studies
  FROM @Studies a1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT a.stID as ha
                FROM @Studies a 
                INNER JOIN @HasStudied wq ON wq.stID = a.stID 
                WHERE a.stID = 'SSS1' AND a.termNbr = 11 
                GROUP BY a.stID 
                HAVING SUM(wq.sPoints) + SUM(a.sPoints) > 50
              ) a2
     ON a1.stID = a2.ha

SELECT *
  FROM @Studies
```

Result:

```
cID stID    sPoints termNbr
BBB SSS2    7       11
BBB SSS2    13      11
```

Comment: I will update the OP with what the data from Studies and HasStudied

Comment: Then maybe you could also provide the points from COURSE for K1 - K5?